# Finding connected components in adjacency matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra, adjacency-list, adjacency-matrix

I was wondering, Is it possible to find the connected components in an adjacency matrix ?

Assuming i have the following adjacency matrix (The cols and rows are not the same node),

[image]

If i draw the adjacency graph it is easy to find the connected components which are :

1)

A2 -> B3

A2 -> B1

A1 -> B1

2)

A3 -> B2

I was wondering is there any operations i can do on the matrix to find the connected components ? and assuming there is a way to find the connected components from the matrix without the need for a graph, why does that method works ? what is the proof ?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Are you looking for something beyond the usual breadth-first-search method?

Comment: Yes, something like switching between rows or cols @beaker